# How do I install Geomatica?

Tags: installation, 11.10, dependencies

I wanted to try the latest version(trial) of Geomatica, Geomatica 2012 on Ubuntu 11.10 beta. When I tried to run the `bin` file I got a whole list of dependencies. It also seems that it is a RPM package. Instead of going through each entry manually, is there any easy way to search and install a list of dependencies? Here is the list what I got -

```
rpm: RPM should not be used directly install RPM packages, use Alien instead!
rpm: However assuming you know what you are doing...
error: Failed dependencies:
glibc >= 2.9 is needed by geomatica-2012-12.0-0.x86_64
libstdc++43 is needed by geomatica-2012-12.0-0.x86_64
libgcc43 is needed by geomatica-2012-12.0-0.x86_64
libgomp43 is needed by geomatica-2012-12.0-0.x86_64
libgfortran43 is needed by geomatica-2012-12.0-0.x86_64
openmotif-libs >= 2.3.1 is needed by geomatica-2012-12.0-0.x86_64
/bin/sh is needed by geomatica-2012-12.0-0.x86_64
libatk-1.0.so.0()(64bit) is needed by geomatica-2012-12.0-0.x86_64
libcairo.so.2()(64bit) is needed by geomatica-2012-12.0-0.x86_64
libcrypto.so.0.9.8()(64bit) is needed by geomatica-2012-12.0-0.x86_64
libcrypt.so.1()(64bit) is needed by geomatica-2012-12.0-0.x86_64
libc.so.6()(64bit) is needed by geomatica-2012-12.0-0.x86_64
libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.2.5)(64bit) is needed by geomatica-2012-12.0-0.x86_64
libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.3.2)(64bit) is needed by geomatica-2012-12.0-0.x86_64
libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.3.4)(64bit) is needed by geomatica-2012-12.0-0.x86_64
libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.3)(64bit) is needed by geomatica-2012-12.0-0.x86_64
libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.7)(64bit) is needed by geomatica-2012-12.0-0.x86_64
libdl.so.2()(64bit) is needed by geomatica-2012-12.0-0.x86_64
libdl.so.2(GLIBC_2.2.5)(64bit) is needed by geomatica-2012-12.0-0.x86_64
libexpat.so.1()(64bit) is needed by geomatica-2012-12.0-0.x86_64
libfontconfig.so.1()(64bit) is needed by geomatica-2012-12.0-0.x86_64
libgcc_s.so.1()(64bit) is needed by geomatica-2012-12.0-0.x86_64
libgcc_s.so.1(GCC_3.0)(64bit) is needed by geomatica-2012-12.0-0.x86_64
libgcc_s.so.1(GCC_4.0.0)(64bit) is needed by geomatica-2012-12.0-0.x86_64
libgdk_pixbuf-2.0.so.0()(64bit) is needed by geomatica-2012-12.0-0.x86_64
libgdk-x11-2.0.so.0()(64bit) is needed by geomatica-2012-12.0-0.x86_64
libgd.so.2()(64bit) is needed by geomatica-2012-12.0-0.x86_64
libgfortran.so.3()(64bit) is needed by geomatica-2012-12.0-0.x86_64
libgfortran.so.3(GFORTRAN_1.0)(64bit) is needed by geomatica-2012-12.0-0.x86_64
libgio-2.0.so.0()(64bit) is needed by geomatica-2012-12.0-0.x86_64
libglib-2.0.so.0()(64bit) is needed by geomatica-2012-12.0-0.x86_64
libGL.so.1()(64bit) is needed by geomatica-2012-12.0-0.x86_64
libgmodule-2.0.so.0()(64bit) is needed by geomatica-2012-12.0-0.x86_64
libgobject-2.0.so.0()(64bit) is needed by geomatica-2012-12.0-0.x86_64
libgomp.so.1()(64bit) is needed by geomatica-2012-12.0-0.x86_64
libgomp.so.1(GOMP_1.0)(64bit) is needed by geomatica-2012-12.0-0.x86_64
libgomp.so.1(OMP_1.0)(64bit) is needed by geomatica-2012-12.0-0.x86_64
libgthread-2.0.so.0()(64bit) is needed by geomatica-2012-12.0-0.x86_64
libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0()(64bit) is needed by geomatica-2012-12.0-0.x86_64
libjpeg.so.62()(64bit) is needed by geomatica-2012-12.0-0.x86_64
libm.so.6()(64bit) is needed by geomatica-2012-12.0-0.x86_64
libm.so.6(GLIBC_2.2.5)(64bit) is needed by geomatica-2012-12.0-0.x86_64
libnsl.so.1()(64bit) is needed by geomatica-2012-12.0-0.x86_64
libpango-1.0.so.0()(64bit) is needed by geomatica-2012-12.0-0.x86_64
libpangocairo-1.0.so.0()(64bit) is needed by geomatica-2012-12.0-0.x86_64
libpangoft2-1.0.so.0()(64bit) is needed by geomatica-2012-12.0-0.x86_64
libpng12.so.0()(64bit) is needed by geomatica-2012-12.0-0.x86_64
libpng12.so.0(PNG12_0)(64bit) is needed by geomatica-2012-12.0-0.x86_64
libpthread.so.0()(64bit) is needed by geomatica-2012-12.0-0.x86_64
libpthread.so.0(GLIBC_2.2.5)(64bit) is needed by geomatica-2012-12.0-0.x86_64
libpthread.so.0(GLIBC_2.3.2)(64bit) is needed by geomatica-2012-12.0-0.x86_64
libpthread.so.0(GLIBC_2.3.4)(64bit) is needed by geomatica-2012-12.0-0.x86_64
libpython2.6.so.1.0()(64bit) is needed by geomatica-2012-12.0-0.x86_64
librt.so.1()(64bit) is needed by geomatica-2012-12.0-0.x86_64
librt.so.1(GLIBC_2.2.5)(64bit) is needed by geomatica-2012-12.0-0.x86_64
libSM.so.6()(64bit) is needed by geomatica-2012-12.0-0.x86_64
libssl.so.0.9.8()(64bit) is needed by geomatica-2012-12.0-0.x86_64
libstdc++.so.6()(64bit) is needed by geomatica-2012-12.0-0.x86_64
libstdc++.so.6(CXXABI_1.3.1)(64bit) is needed by geomatica-2012-12.0-0.x86_64
libstdc++.so.6(CXXABI_1.3)(64bit) is needed by geomatica-2012-12.0-0.x86_64
libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4)(64bit) is needed by geomatica-2012-12.0-0.x86_64
libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.9)(64bit) is needed by geomatica-2012-12.0-0.x86_64
libtiff.so.3()(64bit) is needed by geomatica-2012-12.0-0.x86_64
libutil.so.1()(64bit) is needed by geomatica-2012-12.0-0.x86_64
libX11.so.6()(64bit) is needed by geomatica-2012-12.0-0.x86_64
libXinerama.so.1()(64bit) is needed by geomatica-2012-12.0-0.x86_64
libXm.so.4()(64bit) is needed by geomatica-2012-12.0-0.x86_64
libXt.so.6()(64bit) is needed by geomatica-2012-12.0-0.x86_64
libXxf86vm.so.1()(64bit) is needed by geomatica-2012-12.0-0.x86_64
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ubuntu uses the debian (.deb) packaging mechanism.

A .rpm is a different packaging mechanism called *RPM Package Manager* - you cannot install a .rpm directly on a .deb based distro - and visa versa.

Either download the sources themselves and compile the software or look for a .deb package which you can install.

For some simple .rpm packages you can use "alien"

```
sudo alien -d -i [package_name].rpm
```

This could create a .deb file which you may be able to install.  However, this is very hit-and-miss - strongly suggest find the .deb or compile from source.

Comment: What you say is true about `.rpm` packages. But this is a commercial application which is provided in `.bin` form. I can't expect them to give `.deb` or source for it!

Comment: Then you dont have have many choices - try alien otherwise contact the vendor and request that they release a version for ubuntu.

Comment: Just a small revise, RPM is not called as *Resource Package Mechanism*, it is a recursive acronym: *RPM Package Manager*.

Answer (score 0):

Read the Install.pdf that came with Geomatica carefully - especially near the bottom where it discusses the use of the LD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable.  Once you set up  as they discuss, and possible download a legacy OpenSSl-v0.9.8 that suplies some of the OLD stuff they use (also OpenMotif - old version), it may just work.

I use Centos 6.0 on a AMD 64 bit system. works but is clunky and slow compared to the Win7 version. Shame on them!

Comment: You are able to use it as CentOS natively uses RPM packaging.